# Flutter for loop from list of object and display in row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I make a loop in a `Row` widget?

Here is my list:

```
  List childList = [
    {
      'name': 'Sofie Laurson',
      'old': '39 months',
      'image': 'images/female.jpeg'
    },
    {'name': 'John Snow', 'old': '2 years', 'image': 'images/male.jpeg'}
  ];
```

and here is the `Row`:

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    CircleAvatar(
      radius: 30.0,
      backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/female.jpeg"),
    ),
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Sophie Casey',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          '39 month',
          style: TextStyle(
           fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black45,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Text(
      'Edit',
      style: TextStyle(color: redColor, fontSize: 18.0),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I need to fill the name, image path and age.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

For your problem, I would recommend a `ListView.builder`. It will dynamically build a list and provide you with a build method with an index so you can go through your list. It will repeat until it runs out of items in the list, providing you provide the `itemCount` parameter with a value.

I have made an example on DartPad to illustrate: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/d62f2a463b889e6ed40e521fbe241c8f

UPDATE: I changed the gist behind the DartPad to better match your example of a map in a list.

Comment: Oh, great, thank you very much for help! This is working now :)

Comment: If it helped you, make sure to mark it as the accepted answer so others can see it in search results if they're facing the same issue. :)